# how to load 4 images from url in android?

Tags: android

I want to load four images in four imageview in android
                                                                                                           I try this code and it is run vary good
                                                                                                  but it is load one image>>>>>>>>
                                                                                                  How can I do to load 4 images>>                                                                     I think I need to use array but how??

```
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 new LoadImage().execute("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/630285593268752384/iD1MkFQ0.png");

            }
        });


    }
    private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Image ....");
            pDialog.show();

        }
         protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
             try {
                   bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(args[0]).getContent());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
         }

         protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {

             if(image != null){
             img.setImageBitmap(image);
             b1.setImageBitmap(image);

             pDialog.dismiss();

             }else{

             pDialog.dismiss();
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Does Not exist or Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             }
         }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the ready made libraries... they have async loading, resizing, loading into target to get bitmap... no need to reinvent the wheel (unless it's for study purposes). You can use Picasso, Glide, Fresco... you choose. There is plenty documentation available. Loading is done asynchronously. So you can send multiple requests with multiple urls.